# JavaFX String Encoding Issues

Tags: javafx

I am embedding JavaFX in a Swing application.  I am trying to create a table using the following code and the table headers are nothing but garbage.

```
TableView table = new TableView();
table.setEditable(false);
table.getColumns().setAll(new TableColumn("Col1"), new TableColumn("Col2"));

VBox aVBox = new VBox();
aVBox.setSpacing(5);
aVBox.getChildren().add(table);

jFXPanel.setScene(new Scene(aVBox));
```

The following is what I get on the screen:
[image]

Does anyone know why I don't see "Col1" and "Col2" as the headers?

Comment: Pay attention to the source encoding used by the compiler and the actual encoding used to save the files. There is not enough information to investigate further on this.

Comment: I am on OSX 10.11.5 running Java 1.8.0_51.  I have tried both in Eclipse and using Maven.  My file encoding is UTF-8.  When I compile using Maven I am setting the ${project.build.sourceEncoding} to UTF-8 and I still see the issue.  What other information do you need to investigate further?

Comment: This should be good, cannot think of something else. However do try e.g. to write those characters to a file - always using the correct encoding; how do they look?

Comment: I tried writing the "Col1" and "Col2" strings to a file using UTF-8, US-ASCII, UTF-16, CP1252 and ISO-8859-1 encodings and they all came out fine as I would expect.  I run this same code on windows and it works perfectly.  Is there some encoding setting in JavaFX that I am missing?  All other strings display fine in Swing just not JavaFX.

Comment: The odd thing is I can create a JavaFX charts like Pie Chart or Bar Chart and the text is fine.  However, on the charts if I put a tooltip on something using the following code I get the same garbage text.    Tooltip.install(aNode, new Tooltip(aTooltipString));

Comment: This is strange indeed. I am sorry I cannot think of something else...

Comment: Paste all your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the issue was.  Turns out we were setting the system property:

```
System.setProperty("prism.order", "j2d");
```

There was a comment above this that stated something about a fix for JavaFX beta.  If I took it out then everything was displayed as expected.